# Failing np.nan_to_num function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I'm examining the [Accidental Drug Related Deaths](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/accidental-drug-related-deaths-january-2012-sept-2015) dataset. The following is a list of all drugs:

```
20  Heroin               2529 non-null   object 
 21  Cocaine              1521 non-null   object 
 22  Fentanyl             2232 non-null   object 
 23  FentanylAnalogue     389 non-null    object 
 24  Oxycodone            607 non-null    object 
 25  Oxymorphone          108 non-null    object 
 26  Ethanol              1247 non-null   object 
 27  Hydrocodone          118 non-null    object 
 28  Benzodiazepine       1343 non-null   object 
 29  Methadone            474 non-null    object 
 30  Amphet               159 non-null    object 
 31  Tramad               130 non-null    object 
 32  Morphine_NotHeroin   42 non-null     object 
 33  Hydromorphone        25 non-null     object 
 34  Other                435 non-null    object 
 35  OpiateNOS            88 non-null     object 
 36  AnyOpioid            2466 non-null   object
```

The dataset is sparse, with `Y` in place for each drug cause-of-death. For example, the following is `deaths['Heroin'].head()`:

```
0       NaN
1       NaN
2         Y
3         Y
4       NaN
```

I'm trying to convert this to

```
0.        0
1         0
2         1
3         1
4         0
```

To convert the `Y` to `1`, I've used `deaths = deaths.replace(to_replace={'Y':1})`. I'm now attempting to change the `NaN` to `0`. I'm trying to use `np.nan_to_num()`, but my code doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm using the following:

```
deaths.loc[:,'Heroin':'AnyOpioid'] = np.nan_to_num(deaths.loc[:,'Heroin':'AnyOpioid'])
```

This outputs no change to the original dataset, with `deaths['Heroin'].head()` appearing as

```
0       NaN
1       NaN
2         Y
3         Y
4       NaN
```

(after the prior `deaths.replace()` function).

What is the mechanic that is causing this to happen? I'm assuming it's related to the `.loc`, but I'm not sure what to look at first or how to correct. Removing the `.loc` gives me a `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [Heroin] of <class 'str'>`.

Comment: if you only have `Y` or `nan`, then maybe [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) is what you need like `deaths['Heroin'].notna()`?

Comment: @Ben.T How could I use a Boolean here? Sorry, I'm new to this whole thing.

Comment: Boolean is kind of like 0 and 1, but if you want to see 0 and 1 as values instead of True or False, then use `deaths['Heroin'].notna().astype(int)`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. Write it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Why do you want to use 0/1 instead of actual boolean values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html), giving Boolean `False` if the value is `nan` and `True` if the value is anything else (like `Y` here). To get 0 and 1, you can use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
deaths['Heroin'] = deaths['Heroin'].notna().astype(int)
```